# Get full url from shorten url using python

Tags: python

I am having list of urls like ,

```
l=['bit.ly/1bdDlXc','bit.ly/1bdDlXc',.......,'bit.ly/1bdDlXc']
```

I just want to see the full url from the short one for every element in that list.

Here is my approach,

```
import urllib2

for i in l:
    print urllib2.urlopen(i).url
```

But when list contains thousands of url , the program takes long time.

My question : Is there is any way to reduce execution time or any other approach I have to follow ?

Comment: Might be worth looking at http://dev.bitly.com/ (specifically http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand which allows 15 URLs to be expanded at a time). No doubt there's some Python bitly wrappers on pypi or code.google - but I'll leave you to search for those.

Comment: Do all of the URLs have a hostname of `bit.ly`?

Comment: @Robᵩ s No , all urls not associated with bit.ly

Comment: @JonClements But all urls are not associated with bitly.

Comment: Well, use the bitly api for the ones *that are*... if there's other common shortners, they'll probably have APIs that can be used as well... otherwise, you're stuck with your current approach of seeing where you end up after redirection. You may wish to consider multi-threading/processing to make multiple requests at the same time.

Comment: I wonder if [the Twisted web client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/web/howto/client.html) might be handy here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**First method**

As suggested, one way to accomplish the task would be to use the [official api to bitly](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_expand), which has, however, limitations (e.g., no more than 15 `shortUrl`'s per request).

**Second method**

As an alternative, one could just avoid getting the contents, e.g. by using the `HEAD` HTTP method instead of `GET`.  Here is just a sample code, which makes use of the excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package:

```
import requests

l=['bit.ly/1bdDlXc','bit.ly/1bdDlXc',.......,'bit.ly/1bdDlXc']

for i in l:
    print requests.head("http://"+i).headers['location']
```

Comment: As a bonus, `requests.head()` doesn't follow the redirection, so it saves at least one HTTP transaction.

Comment: Actually it doesn't return the link, see my answer

Answer (score 2):

```py
from requests import get

def get_real_url_from_shortlink(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    return resp.url
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try twisted's asynchronous web client. Be careful with this, though, it doesn't rate-limit at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred, DeferredList, DeferredLock
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from twisted.web.client import Agent, HTTPConnectionPool
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
from pprint import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
from urlparse import urlparse
from random import randrange
import fileinput

pool = HTTPConnectionPool(reactor)
pool.maxPersistentPerHost = 16
agent = Agent(reactor, pool)
locks = defaultdict(DeferredLock)
locations = {}

def getLock(url, simultaneous = 1):
    return locks[urlparse(url).netloc, randrange(simultaneous)]

@inlineCallbacks
def getMapping(url):
    # Limit ourselves to 4 simultaneous connections per host
    # Tweak this as desired, but make sure that it no larger than
    # pool.maxPersistentPerHost
    lock = getLock(url,4)
    yield lock.acquire()
    try:
        resp = yield agent.request('HEAD', url)
        locations[url] = resp.headers.getRawHeaders('location',[None])[0]
    except Exception as e:
        locations[url] = str(e)
    finally:
        lock.release()


dl = DeferredList(getMapping(url.strip()) for url in fileinput.input())
dl.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
pprint(locations)
```